# как получить неформатируемый json

Tags: php, json, yii2

файл:

```
{
  "participants": [
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u008c\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u00a8\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u009a\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00bb \u00d0\u009a\u00d1\u0083\u00d1\u0088\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0080"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u009c\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bc \u00d0\u009b\u00d1\u008e\u00d0\u00b1\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b2"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u009c\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bc \u00d0\u009f\u00d1\u0083\u00d1\u0085"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0090\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00a0\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00bc\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b9"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0094\u00d0\u00b0\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u008c\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b0"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u00b3\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u008c \u00d0\u0093\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0085"
    },
    {
      "name": "Pavel  Geptner"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0090\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b4\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00a1\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00bc\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b2"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "\u00d0\u0090\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00a0\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00bc\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b9",
      "timestamp_ms": 1543941856123,
      "content": "https://www.facebook.com/716628253/posts/10157110751043254/",
      "share": {
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/shipachev/posts/10157110751043254"
      },
      "type": "Share"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "\u00d0\u009c\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bc \u00d0\u009b\u00d1\u008e\u00d0\u00b1\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b2",
      "timestamp_ms": 1543822921939,
      "content": "\u00d0\u00b2\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bc \u00d0\u00bf\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0082, \u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u008b\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u00b2 \u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b8 \u00d0\u00b8 \u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b0\u00d1\u0088\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bb \u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0083\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b8 \u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u008f yii2, \u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b1\u00d1\u008f\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b0 \u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u008f\u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00b0\u00d1\u008e\u00d1\u0082 \u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0083\u00d0\u00b6\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u008b\u00d0\u00b5 \u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00b6\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0082\u00d1\u008b:\nhttps://www.2amigos.us/open-source?page=1&per-page=9",
      "share": {
        "link": "https://www.2amigos.us/open-source?page=1&per-page=9"
      },
      "type": "Share"
    }
  ],
  "title": "\u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u0097\u00d0\u0091\u00d0\u0090.tech",
  "is_still_participant": true,
  "thread_type": "RegularGroup",
  "thread_path": "archived_threads/IZBAtech_oV-Kxgzzjg"
}
```

`

выполняю

`Json::decode(file_get_contents($this->getFolder() . $this->fileName($file)))`

получаю

```
array(6) { ["participants"]=> array(9) { [0]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(33) "ÐÐ»ÑÑ Ð¨Ð¾ÑÑ" } [1]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(49) "ÐÐ¸ÑÐ¸Ð»Ð» ÐÑÑÐ½Ð¸Ñ" } [2]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(61) "ÐÐ°ÐºÑÐ¸Ð¼ ÐÑÐ±Ð¸ÑÐµÐ»ÐµÐ²" } [3]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(37) "ÐÐ°ÐºÑÐ¸Ð¼ ÐÑÑ" } [4]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(65) "ÐÐ»ÐµÐºÑÐµÐ¹ Ð Ð°Ð¼ÐµÐ½ÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹" } [5]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(49) "ÐÐ°ÑÑÑ ÐÐ²Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð°" } [6]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(49) "ÐÐ³Ð¾ÑÑ ÐÐ»Ð°Ð´ÐºÐ¸Ñ" } [7]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(14) "Pavel Geptner" } [8]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(61) "ÐÐ½Ð´ÑÐµÐ¹ Ð¡Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ð¼Ð¾Ð½Ð¾Ð²" } } ["messages"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["sender_name"]=> string(65) "ÐÐ»ÐµÐºÑÐµÐ¹ Ð Ð°Ð¼ÐµÐ½ÑÐºÐ¸Ð¹" ["timestamp_ms"]=> int(1543941856123) ["content"]=> string(59) "https://www.facebook.com/716628253/posts/10157110751043254/" ["share"]=> array(1) { ["link"]=> string(58) "https://www.facebook.com/shipachev/posts/10157110751043254" } ["type"]=> string(5) "Share" } [1]=> array(5) { ["sender_name"]=> string(61) "ÐÐ°ÐºÑÐ¸Ð¼ ÐÑÐ±Ð¸ÑÐµÐ»ÐµÐ²" ["timestamp_ms"]=> int(1543822921939) ["content"]=> string(333) "Ð²ÑÐµÐ¼ Ð¿ÑÐ¸Ð²ÐµÑ, ÑÑÐ»ÑÑ Ð² ÑÐµÑÐ¸ Ð¸ Ð½Ð°ÑÐµÐ» Ð²ÐºÑÑÐ½Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸ Ð´Ð»Ñ yii2, ÑÐµÐ±ÑÑÐ° ÑÑÑÑÐ¿Ð°ÑÑ Ð½ÑÐ¶Ð½ÑÐµ Ð²Ð¸Ð´Ð¶Ð¸ÑÑ: https://www.2amigos.us/open-source?page=1&per-page=9" ["share"]=> array(1) { ["link"]=> string(52) "https://www.2amigos.us/open-source?page=1&per-page=9" } ["type"]=> string(5) "Share" } } ["title"]=> string(21) "ÐÐÐÐ.tech" ["is_still_participant"]=> bool(true) ["thread_type"]=> string(12) "RegularGroup" ["thread_path"]=> string(36) "archived_threads/IZBAtech_oV-Kxgzzjg" }
```

как мне получить вместо этого

```
["name"]=> string(33) "ÐÐ»ÑÑ Ð¨Ð¾ÑÑ"
```

это

```
["name"]=> string(33) "\u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u008c\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u00a8\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082"
```

Comment: для чего вам получать такую строку? `\u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u008c\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u00a8\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$str = '{
  "participants": [
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u008c\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u00a8\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u009a\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00bb \u00d0\u009a\u00d1\u0083\u00d1\u0088\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0080"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u009c\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bc \u00d0\u009b\u00d1\u008e\u00d0\u00b1\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b2"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u009c\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bc \u00d0\u009f\u00d1\u0083\u00d1\u0085"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0090\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00a0\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00bc\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b9"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0094\u00d0\u00b0\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u008c\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b0"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u00b3\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u008c \u00d0\u0093\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0085"
    },
    {
      "name": "\u00d0\u0090\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b4\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00a1\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00bc\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00be\u00d0\u00b2"
    }
  ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "sender_name": "\u00d0\u0090\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b9 \u00d0\u00a0\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00bc\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00ba\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b9",
      "timestamp_ms": 1543941856123,
      "content": "https://www.facebook.com/716628253/posts/10157110751043254/",
      "share": {
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/shipachev/posts/10157110751043254"
      },
      "type": "Share"
    },
    {
      "sender_name": "\u00d0\u009c\u00d0\u00b0\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00bc \u00d0\u009b\u00d1\u008e\u00d0\u00b1\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bb\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b2",
      "timestamp_ms": 1543822921939,
      "content": "\u00d0\u00b2\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bc \u00d0\u00bf\u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0082, \u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u008b\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u008f \u00d0\u00b2 \u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00b5\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b8 \u00d0\u00b8 \u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00b0\u00d1\u0088\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00bb \u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00ba\u00d1\u0083\u00d1\u0081\u00d0\u00bd\u00d0\u00be\u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b8 \u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u008f yii2, \u00d1\u0080\u00d0\u00b5\u00d0\u00b1\u00d1\u008f\u00d1\u0082\u00d0\u00b0 \u00d1\u0081\u00d1\u0082\u00d1\u0080\u00d1\u008f\u00d0\u00bf\u00d0\u00b0\u00d1\u008e\u00d1\u0082 \u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u0083\u00d0\u00b6\u00d0\u00bd\u00d1\u008b\u00d0\u00b5 \u00d0\u00b2\u00d0\u00b8\u00d0\u00b4\u00d0\u00b6\u00d0\u00b8\u00d1\u0082\u00d1\u008b:\nhttps://www.2amigos.us/open-source?page=1&per-page=9",
      "share": {
        "link": "https://www.2amigos.us/open-source?page=1&per-page=9"
      },
      "type": "Share"
    }
  ],
  "title": "\u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u0097\u00d0\u0091\u00d0\u0090",
  "is_still_participant": true,
  "thread_type": "RegularGroup",
  "thread_path": "archived_threads"
}';
```

---

```
$json = changeCharset(json_decode($str, TRUE));

function changeCharset( $array ){
    array_walk_recursive( $array, function(&$item) { 
       $item = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $item); 
    });

    return $array;
}
```

---

Результат:

```
array(6) {
  ["participants"]=>
  array(8) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(17) "Вася Центр"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(25) "Артем Лор"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(31) "Дима Ковалчук"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(19) "Гена Конь"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(33) "Рая Гермовна"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(25) "Паша Ветер"
    }
    [6]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(25) "Кот"
    }
    [7]=>
    array(1) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(31) "Гоша Купер"
    }
  }
  ["messages"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["sender_name"]=>
      string(33) "Гоша Купер"
      ["timestamp_ms"]=>
      string(13) "1543941856123"
      ["content"]=>
      string(59) "https://www.facebook.com/716628253/posts/10157110751043254/"
      ["share"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["link"]=>
        string(58) "https://www.facebook.com/shipachev/posts/10157110751043254"
      }
      ["type"]=>
      string(5) "Share"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["sender_name"]=>
      string(31) "Паша Ветер"
      ["timestamp_ms"]=>
      string(13) "1543822921939"
      ["content"]=>
      string(203) "всем привет, рылся в сети и нашел вкусности для yii2, ребята стряпают нужные виджиты:
https://www.2amigos.us/open-source?page=1&per-page=9"
      ["share"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["link"]=>
        string(52) "https://www.2amigos.us/open-source?page=1&per-page=9"
      }
      ["type"]=>
      string(5) "Share"
    }
  }
  ["title"]=>
  string(13) "tech"
  ["is_still_participant"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["thread_type"]=>
  string(12) "RegularGroup"
  ["thread_path"]=>
  string(16) "archived_threads"
}
```

Теперь находите нужное Вам значение и меняйте его. 
[Online решение](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a92a710236aa09c8c7723b7043d23c1957553739)

Comment: Вопрос такой, если попадается символы на кириллице, как можно это обработать?

Comment: @MaximLyubitelev не понял вопроса

Comment: если в файле json есть к примеру, в место этого: "name": "\u00d0\u0098\u00d0\u00bb\u00d1\u008c\u00d1\u008f", будет это "name": "фцвфцвфцвфцвфцвфцвцфвцфв". то к сожалению будет ошибка, как ее можно обработать? сейчас пробую mb_detect_encoding, но что то задумка не очень. Спасибо

Comment: @MaximLyubitelev `json_decode` - что вам возвращает?

Comment: мне возвращает iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string. в строке $item = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $item);

Comment: если сделать так $item = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $item); то функция пропустит значения с этой строкой, а надо что бы вернула значение на кириллице

Comment: @MaximLyubitelev а если заменить `TRANSLIT` на `IGNORE` - он удалит все символы которые не может преобразовать

Comment: так я не хочу удалять, там важные строки, как их просто пропускать?

Comment: @MaximLyubitelev даже не знаю чем вам помочь

Comment: @MaximLyubitelev сделайте кодировку файла в UTF-8 и не должно быть у вас проблем

Comment: он и так UTF-8, в любом случае, спасибо за помощь.